# Split table vs. same values in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table `products`:

```
#products
ID | category | type | criteria1 | criteria2
```

, with `category` and `type` being foreign keys of other tables.

Should I split this table up into `category1_type1_products`, `category1_type2_products` and so on? It seems to me I should, because right now in my table, there are some thousands of entries with the same `ID` and `category` value. Loads of redundand information.

Also, a query could perform faster if mysql didn't have to search for all rows with the specific category and type first. (right?)

Is this recommended structuring behaviour at all? If not, what if my table has got 5 million tuples?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "split up" a table, because there are two different ways to split up a table.  There is a horizontal split, where records go in one table or the other.  There is also a vertical split, better known as decomposing a table, where fields go in one table or the other, except for a key field that goes in both.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to split a table horizontally.  You can get the same speed benefits (just about) by partitioning a table (if your DBMS supports it), without all the drawbacks.

Comment: Redundancy isn't always harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the Question

```
#products
ID | category | type | criteria1 | criteria2
```

> right now in my table, there are some thousands of entries with the
>   same ID and category value

So, I don't see those rows as product entities as you have it, but rather as de-normalized data violating [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) or 3NF.

I would restructure the schema with junction tables. Seeing the whole schema and sample data would help. The `criteria(n)` columns only complicate it, potentially, more.

In normalized designs, data is highly maintainable, and an entity is an entity. Joins are fast, as they utilize indexes (hopefully thin), and tablescans are avoided. Running queries thru [Explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) certainly turns on the sonar of the slow tablescan problem. A well written article on `Explain` is [Using EXPLAIN to Write Better MySQL Queries](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't define any of the attributes so it's impossible to recommend anything. Is the `criteria1` field functionally dependent on `Category` and `criteria2` functionally dependent on `Type` or `Category` and `Type` together? Then you have a normalization issue. If `criteria1` and `criteria2` are both functionally dependent on the combination of `Category` and `Type`, then there is no issue.

In that case, if you're just worried about performance, then know that a few thousand entries is not a large table. When you get to a few hundred million, then you are approaching largeness.

But create an index on (`Category`, `Type`) and you won't have a problem, even then.